# List the fields for every shapefile I have stored in a list

Tags: arcpy, fields-attributes, list

I am trying to list the fields for every shapefile in 2 lists I have created to prove that each shapefile with the correct projection/feature type within one of the lists got X, Y coordinates added to their attribute table. In order to do so, I have created two empty lists before using a for loop, and appended them using if/else.

To prove that I was able to separate the shapefiles and append them accordingly, I need to list the fields for both lists of shapefiles. My problem is that I can only figure out how to list the fields for a single shapefile, rather than the lists I have created. Here is the code I have so far:

```
arcpy.env.workspace = 'C:/python/week_03/week_03/data'
srs = 'NAD_1983_UTM_Zone_12N'
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace
print(srs)

arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(feature_type='Point')
shapefiles = list(arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(feature_type='point'))
print(list(shapefiles))
out: ['data1.shp', 'data2.shp', 'data3.shp', 'data4.shp', 'sample1.shp', 'sample2.shp', 'sample3.shp', 'sample_points.shp']

UTM = []
noUTM = []
for fc in shapefiles:
    spatial_ref = arcpy.Describe(fc).spatialReference.name
    if spatial_ref == srs:
        arcpy.management.AddXY(fc)
        UTM.append(fc)
    else:
        noUTM.append(fc)
print(UTM)
print(noUTM)

out:['data1.shp', 'data3.shp', 'data4.shp', 'sample1.shp', 
'sample2.shp', 'sample3.shp', 'sample_points.shp']
['data2.shp']
```

Here's where I'm getting tripped up. How do I alter this line of code to get it to list the fields of the UTM list I've created? The example below is a line that works to get the fields for one specific shapefile.

```
fieldlist = arcpy.ListFields('data2.shp')
[field.name for field in arcpy.ListFields('data2.shp')]
```

Comment: You should probably review your Python fundamentals notes for how to use a dictionary. Then you can lookup field names by file name.

Answer (score 1):

Use ListFields with a foor loop:

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\GIS\data\Bakgrundskartor_LMV\Hamta_data_ladda_postgis\sve_1milj_Sweref_99_TM_shape\svk\riks"
feature_classes = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
#['ak_riks.shp', 'al_riks.shp', 'an_riks.shp', 'bs_riks.shp', 'bt_riks.shp', 'hl_riks.shp', 'jl_riks.shp', 'mb_riks.shp', 'ml_riks.shp', ...

for fc in feature_classes:
    #List field objects
    fields = [f for f in arcpy.ListFields(dataset=fc)] #[<Field object at 0x1e4bf852f10[0x1e4be1a7df0]>, <Field object at 0x1e4bf852e50[0x1e4be1a7d30]>, ...
    #Extract their names
    fieldnames = [f.name for f in fields] #['FID', 'Shape', 'KKOD', 'KATEGORI', 'VAGNR1', 'VAGNR2', 'VAGNR3']
```